# VueJs Lazy initialization of tab's component just once

Tags: vue.js, tabs, lazy-initialization, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to make the bootstrap-vue tabs initialization lazy and though it works if i set the lazy attribute on true, it render the component every time i'm visiting a specific tab:

BtabsWrapper.vue:

```
<b-tabs
    :lazy="true"
  >
    <b-tab
      v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
      :key="'li-tab-' + index"
      :title="tab.title"
      :href="'#' + tab.id"
    >
      <slot
        :name="tab.id"
      />
    </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
```

I need more of a lazy initialization of each tab(just once) rather than re rendering the tab's component every time the user visits it. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe checkout [`keep-alive`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) if you haven't yet. I haven't use bootstrap-vue tabs before so I'm not 100% if `keep-alive` can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap the content of each tab in a `v-if` and change that condition once when they're loaded you should get your desired outcome.

And in your case if you're using a `v-for`, you can utilize the index in your `v-for` in the includes part as `visitedTabs.includes(index)`

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        visitedTabs: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onInput(value) {
        if(!this.visitedTabs.includes(value)){
          this.visitedTabs.push(value)
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.4/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.4/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-card clas no-body>
    <b-tabs card @input="onInput">
      <b-tab title="First tab">
        <div v-if="visitedTabs.includes(0)">
          Hello World
        </div>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Second tab">
        <div v-if="visitedTabs.includes(1)">
          <b-input />
        </div>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Third tab">
        <div v-if="visitedTabs.includes(2)">
          <b-checkbox />
        </div>
      </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

Comment: I've used your suggestion, thank you and sorry for the delay